# Writing xml file and saving to drive in google script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to take information from an excel sheet and convert it manually into an xml file format, then saving it into google drive only using code. 
I'd like to know if there's an equivalent to the **xmlbuilder** from node js in the google sheet script editor.
Thanks, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

- You have an excel file (I assume `xls` or `xlsx`) in Drive.
- You want to create an XML file based on data coming from this file.
- You want to achieve this using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

If that's the case, one way ahead could be to follow these steps:

#### - Convert to Google Spreadsheet:

one way would be to first convert the original file to a Google Spreadsheet that can be used by SpreadsheetApp, and extract data from there. To achieve that, you could do something along the following lines:

```js
var xlsId = "your-file-id";
var xls = DriveApp.getFileById(xlsId);
var blob = xls.getBlob();
var file = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, {convert:true});
var id = file["id"];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
```

This code uses [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to create a Google Spreadsheet out of the blob you get from the excel file, via [Drive.Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert). Then, you can easily access this newly created file via SpreadsheetApp.

(Bear in mind that this will create a new file every time you run it. Use [Files.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete) to avoid that).

#### - Extract data from Spreadsheet:

You can then extract the data you want via [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). Let's say, for example, that you can to get all content from a certain sheet. You could do something like this:

```js
var values = ss.getSheetByName("sheet-name").getDataRange().getValues();
```

#### - Create XML via XmlService:

Finally, you could create an XML out of this data if you use the [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service). Check the function called `createXml` in the link I provided. It can give you an idea of how to create the XML (I cannot be more precise since you didn't provide more information on what exactly you want to do). Some important methods that you might want to use are [createDocument](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#createdocumentrootelement) and [createElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#createelementname).

I hope this is of any help.